# Export list to excel using asp.net core set header style

Tags: asp.net-core, openxml, export-to-excel

I'm exporting data to excel. I would like to add excel header color and header width. I tried different way but not working. Please see my below function. I'm using asp.net and OpenXml library. Any one expert here to suggest any solution. Thanks

```
public byte[] ExportExcelFile<T>(List<T> data, string sheetName)
        {
            var table = ToDataTable(data);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();

                var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                var sheetData = new SheetData();
                sheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

                var sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
                var relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                sheets.Append(new Sheet { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = 1, Name = sheetName });

                var headerRow = new Row();

                var columns = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                    var cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                {
                    var newRow = new Row();
                    foreach (var col in columns)
                    {
                        var cell = new Cell();
                        cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }

                workbook.Save();
                workbook.Close();
            }

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer the following steps to add css style for the excel content:

1. Add Stylesheet. Create a GenerateStylesheet class and contain the following code:

   ```
    private Stylesheet GenerateStylesheet()
    {
        Stylesheet styleSheet = null;

        //Fonts can have one or more Font children which each have different properties like FontSize, Bold, Color, and etc.
        //Here, we add two Font children to the Fonts object. The first one is the default font use by all cells, and the second one is specific to header.
        Fonts fonts = new Fonts(
            new Font( // Index 0 - default
                new FontSize() { Val = 10 }

            ),
            new Font( // Index 1 - header
                new FontSize() { Val = 10 },
                new Bold(),
                new Color() { Rgb = "FFFFFF" }

            ));
        //Fills can have one or more Fill children which you can set its ForegroundColor.
        Fills fills = new Fills(
                new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.None }), // Index 0 - default
                new Fill(new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125 }), // Index 1 - default
                new Fill(new PatternFill(new ForegroundColor { Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() { Value = "66666666" } })
                { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid }) // Index 2 - header
            );
        //Borders can have one or more Border children which each defines how the border should look like
        Borders borders = new Borders(
                new Border(), // index 0 default
                new Border( // index 1 black border
                    new LeftBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                    new RightBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                    new TopBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                    new BottomBorder(new Color() { Auto = true }) { Style = BorderStyleValues.Thin },
                    new DiagonalBorder())
            );
        //CellFormats which has one or many CellFormat children. Each CellFormat gets the index of Font, Border, Fill, or etc. 
        CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats(
                new CellFormat(), // default
                new CellFormat { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 1, ApplyBorder = true }, // body
                new CellFormat { FontId = 1, FillId = 2, BorderId = 1, ApplyFill = true } // header
            );

        styleSheet = new Stylesheet(fonts, fills, borders, cellFormats);

        return styleSheet;
    }
   ```
2. Add the style to the workbook.

   Add a WorkbookStylePart to the WorkbookPart and initialize its Stylesheet:

   ```
    //Add a WorkbookStylePart to the WorkbookPart and initialize its Stylesheet:
    WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    stylePart.Stylesheet = GenerateStylesheet();
    stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();
   ```
3. Add style to Cells

   ```
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

        var cell = new Cell();
        cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
        cell.StyleIndex = 2; //add css style to Cells
        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
    }
   ```

   The Complete ExportExcelFile code:

   ```
    public byte[] ExportExcelFile<T>(List<T> data, string sheetName)
    {
        var table = ToDataTable(data);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();

            //Add a WorkbookStylePart to the WorkbookPart and initialize its Stylesheet:
            WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
            stylePart.Stylesheet = GenerateStylesheet();
            stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();

            var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new SheetData();
            sheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

            var sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
            var relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

            sheets.Append(new Sheet { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = 1, Name = sheetName });

            var headerRow = new Row();

            var columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                var cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                cell.StyleIndex = 2; //add css style to Cells
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                var newRow = new Row();
                foreach (var col in columns)
                {
                    var cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    cell.StyleIndex = 1; //add css style to Cells
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
        }

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
   ```

Then, when export excel using the above code:

```
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        List<Employee> Students = new List<Employee>(){
            new Employee() { Name = "Pradeep", salary = 15000, EmpId = 100 },
             new Employee() { Name = "Smith", salary = 25000, EmpId = 101},
            new Employee() { Name = "John", salary = 21000, EmpId = 102 }
        };

        byte[] result = ExportExcelFile<Employee>(Students, "sheetA");
        return File(result, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Grid.xlsx");
        //return View();
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]

**Update:**

To set the columns width, you could update the ExportExcelFile method as below:

```
    public byte[] ExportExcelFile<T>(List<T> data, string sheetName)
    {
        var table = ToDataTable(data);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

            // Adding style
            WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
            stylePart.Stylesheet = GenerateStylesheet();
            stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();

            // Setting up columns
            Columns widthcolumns = new Columns(
                    new Column // first column
                    {
                        Min = 1,
                        Max = 1,
                        Width = 20,
                        CustomWidth = true
                    },
                    new Column // second columns
                    {
                        Min = 2,
                        Max = 3,
                        Width = 15,
                        CustomWidth = true
                    },
                    new Column // third column
                    {
                        Min = 4,
                        Max = 4,
                        Width = 8,
                        CustomWidth = true
                    });

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(widthcolumns);
            Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = sheetName }; 
            sheets.Append(sheet); 
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save(); 
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

            var headerRow = new Row();

            var columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                var cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                cell.StyleIndex = 2; //add css style to Cells
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                var newRow = new Row();
                foreach (var col in columns)
                {
                    var cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    cell.StyleIndex = 1; //add css style to Cells
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
        }

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, its working fine. I need to keep excel column width 200px . How can I add width ? Thanks !

Comment: Please check the Update, to set the column width, you could use the Columns class and append the columns to work worksheet: `worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(columns);`. But from the [definition of the column class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEyRP.png), we can see the width property is a double value, so, you can't set it to `200px`.